# How to connect two adapters to aws linux 2 with virtulabox?

Tags: amazon-web-services, virtualbox, amazon-linux, amazon-linux-2

I followed this video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oYo1LHbEKyI) and able to use amazon linux 2 with virtualbox.

But this video shows only one network adapter(bridged).

I connected two network adapters(NAT and Host-Only) but only the first adapter is visible.

I didn't configure through command line, Instead I added the adapters in the vm configuration.

[adapter 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNYD5.png)

Second one is not detected.

As you can see eth1 is not enabled.

[ip a s -- output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2vqZ.png)

Even nmtui and nmtcli commands doesn't work.

ifup eth1 also not detecting the eth1 adapter.

```
[ec2-user@amazonlinux ~]$ ifup eth1
/usr/sbin/ifup: configuration for eth1 not found.
Usage: ifup <configuration>
```

How to enable that?

Comment: how do you configure the interfaces via systemd or /etc/network/interfaces?

Comment: I didn't configure through command line, Instead I added the adapters in the vm configuration.